# I can't set the StreamingLogLevel in spark2

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, spark-streaming

[image]

[image]

I can't extends Logging object,because it is the kind of private,how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Logging object you are referring to is internal to Spark and can't be used. Instead, you can create your own mixin doing same thing, or just stick to [standard log4j practice](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm) of creating log fields in every class.